# Impersonate user in WCF from multiple callers

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-security, impersonation, delegation

I'm using WCF services ensuring that UserName/Password must be provided for each request. I need use same service from many clients, but I need impersonate the call to access the appropriate resources for each client. When I call the service directly from the client there is no problem, because I use for each client a pair UserName/Password defined in theirs web.config. The problem came when I need to call a second Web service from a call to the first-one using the same identity. This second Web service requires UserName/Password, but I only know who is the caller (UserName) but not the password.

How I can impersonate this second call without knowing the password for the corresponding username?

**EDIT**: The app (Web App and Services) is running in a shared hosting environment where I can't use Windows Authentication to configure Kerberos for Delegation. I have defined a UserNameValidator to process on each call the pair UserName/Password against a custom SQLServer database. Moreover, the intended customers of this app will use it from Internet, without requiring a windows account, that is because I need a more flexible, SQL-based, authentication schema.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921978/asp-net-website-wcf-service-wcf-service-with-impersonation-all-the-way/2922002#2922002

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at using [Kerberos](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/1e69f40a-720e-4d72-8861-4aae6a72bbea) to handle the passing of authentication onwards to other services from your first WCF service.

Comment: The problem is that I'm in a shared hosting and I'm not using Windows Authentication, but custom Username/Password authentication method, using an UserNameValidator implementation to validate those credential on each call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the declarative security options? [The linked article by Juval Lowy includes an internet application scenario as well.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163382.aspx)